# Can't go through the array object received from the service but I can see its content

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, service, return-type

When I try to access to the array it returns `undefined`.
It is as if what I receive were inside another element, because in the console the array is not accessed directly, but rather you have to open a tab to see it.
[Console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4hiI.png)

See the json response on Postman:
[json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKtPq.png)

That's the code of the component:

```js
  fetchHolidays(){
    this.calendarService.fetchDates(this.year)
    .subscribe((dates)=>{
      console.log(dates);
      console.log(dates.length);
      console.log(dates[0]);
      this.holidays=dates;
      this.updatedVariables=true;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
      //this.holidays=[];
    }
    );
  }
```

That's the code of the model Calendar:

```js
export class Calendar{
    public date: string= '';
    public type: TypeDate = new TypeDate; 
}

export class TypeDate{
    public id: number = 0;
    public descripcion: String = ''; 
}
```

That's the code of my service:

```
public fetchDates(year: number): Observable<Calendar[]>{
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${year}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Calendar[]>(url);
}
```

I have tried to extract the data by changing the model:

```js
export class ContentCalendar{
    public calendar: Calendar[]=[];
}

export class Calendar{
    public date: string= '';
    public type: TypeDate = new TypeDate; 
}

export class TypeDate{
    public id: number = 0;
    public descripcion: String = ''; 
}
```

At my component:

```js
  fetchHolidays(){
    this.calendarService.fetchDates(this.year)
    .subscribe((contentCalendar)=>{
      console.log(contentCalendar);
      console.log(contentCalendar['calendar'][0]['date'])
      console.log(contentCalendar.calendar[0].date);
```

And the error is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`
[Console object information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k93GV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was asking the model what the interface does.
I have created an interface just like the last model and I have already been able to access the data. I leave here the example of the interface:

```js
export interface Holidays {
    content: Content[];
}

export interface Content {
    date: string;
    type: Type;
}

export interface Type {
    id:          number;
    description: string;
}
```

I also leave the example of the request to the service and the console.log:

```js
  fetchHolidays(){
    this.calendarService.fetchDates(this.year)
    .subscribe((holidays)=>{
      console.log(holidays.content[1].date);
      this.updatedVariables=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your dates variable is not an array. It's an object whose property (content property) holds an array. You expect:

```
dates:Array<Calendar>
```

What it actually is:

```
dates: {
  content: Array<Calendar>
}
```

Simply, you should `dates.content.length` or `dates.content[0]`, you probably overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image, when you are doing this:

```
.subscribe((dates)=>{....
```

what you are really doing is this:

```
.subscribe( (dates: Calendar[])=>{
```

So, when you are trying to do *this.holidays=dates;*, holidays should be Calendar[] type as well.

**To sum up**,
dates is something like this array:

```
[ 
   {  
      date:"01/01/2021",
      type: {
               id: 1,
               descripcion: "Some text like first date or wahtever..."
            }
   },
   {  date:"01/06/2021",
      type: {...}
   },
....
];
```

So, for instance, if you declare *const* firstElement = dates[0];
, then firstElement would be:

```
 {  
      date:"01/01/2021",
      type:  {
               id: 1,
               descripcion: "Some text like first date or wahtever..."
             }
 }
```

So **you can access to field date, doing something like this**:

```
const myFirstItem = dates[0];
const myFirstItemDate = myFirstItem?.date;
const myFirstItemId = myFirstItem?.type?.id;
const myFirstItemDescription = myFirstItem?.type?.descripcion;
```

I hope this "step-by-step" exhibition of how to extract the data of your API response Json helps you.

Comment: sorry I have not given all the information that I should give, thanks for the explanation but I have already tried that. I think the model does not fit the json.